# What is the difference between the 'radio-terms' and 'jargon' tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have [radio-terms](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-terms) and [jargon](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon) tags, with three questions in each and none tagged using both.

[radio-terms](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-terms) has no tag wiki currently, whereas [jargon](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon) has the following:

> Questions about acronyms, words, phrases, or other terminology specific to amateur radio.

Frankly, I find the distinction somewhat confusing. Do we really need both tags? I expect there to be a lot of mis-tagging if we have both. For one, [JOTA](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/116/29) is most definitely not a common-radio term, but rather amateur radio specific, yet is still tagged [radio-term](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-term) rather than the appropriate [jargon](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon) (as it is amateur radio specific). Also, if as an asker you've come across a term that you don't understand and want to ask about, how would you know whether it is a general radio term or an amateur-radio-specific term, to be able to tag the question correctly?

I do realize that there will be some questions which are about one but does not fit into the other, but really, **do we need both these tags?** *Personally I think we could do quite well with just one of them,* at least to begin with. It's unlikely we'll get so many such questions in such a short period of time that retagging would constitute an insurmountable effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like these are a clear cut synonym. I would just use [jargon](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon).

Comment: [tag:radio-terms] -> [tag:jargon] synonym created.